# Получить JSON объект

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit, объекты

Есть следующая структура ссылки:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения] 
Необходимо получить объект: "title: тип кузова", *используя библиотеку retrofit*.
Получил одно значение следующим способом:

MainActivity.class

```
public void onResponse(Call<DropDown> call, Response<DropDown> response) {
            DropDown jsonResponse = response.body();
            Log.d("key",jsonResponse.getForm().getUser()+"");
}



public class Form {
@SerializedName("offer_type")
String user;

public String getUser() {
    return user;
}
```

Как корректно возможно прописать в классе Form "путь" к запрашиваемому **title**?

P.S. Буду рад любому дополнительному материалу по данной теме.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Пример 1**
Допустим, у вас есть такой JSON-объект:

```
{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": 2
}
```

Этот объект содержит два поля с примитивным типом. Его можно распарсить таким классом:

```
pulib class Form {
    @Serializedname("param1")
    String mString;
    @Serializedname("param2")
    int mInt
}
```

**Пример 2**
НО что делать, если в JSON-объекте вложен другой JSON-объект?

```
{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": 2,
    "nestedObj": {
       "param31":"lol",
       "pararam":"yahoo!"
    }
}
```

Для такого объекта подойдет вот такой класс:

```
public class Form {
    @SerializedName("param1")
    String mString;
    @SerializedName("param2")
    int mInt
    @SerializedName("nestedObj")
    NestedObj mNestedObj;

   public class NestedObj {
     @SerializedName("param31")
     String mString1;
     @SerializedName("pararam")
     String mString2;
   }
}
```

**Пример 3**
Но у вас еще сложнее, у вас в объекте вложенный массив. Тоже не проблема.

```
{
    "param1": "value1",
    "param2": 2,
    "nestedObj": [
      {
        "param31":"lol",
        "pararam":"yahoo!"
       },
       {
        "param31":"lololo",
        "pararam":"fantastic!!"
       },
       {
        "param31":"lolololo",
        "pararam":"WOW!"
       }
     ]
}
```

Новый клаcc почти не отличается от того, что был в примере 2:

```
public class Form {
    @SerializedName("param1")
    String mString;
    @SerializedName("param2")
    int mInt
    @SerializedName("nestedObj")
    Collection<NestedObj> mNestedObj;

   public class NestedObj {
     @SerializedName("param31")
     String mString1;
     @SerializedName("pararam")
     String mString2;
   }
}
```

Вместо `Collection` можно также использовать `List` или `ArrayList`
Эти три примера - исчерпыващи для того, чтобы распарсить любой JSON

Comment: Полностью с Вами согласен! **Большое спасибо за** настолько развернутый **ответ**.

Comment: Культура общения на StackOverflow призывает пользователей отмечать ответы, которые решили их проблему, как правильные, т.е. зеленой галочкой под индикатором голосов

Comment: Ради одного значения из многоярусных json'ов создавать pojo классы для всей иерархии смысла нет. Для этого есть механизм десериализаторов. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23070298/get-nested-json-object-with-gson-using-retrofit

Comment: @P. Ilyin Готово, спасибо.
Но дополнительно, желающие смогут добавить мой вопрос ответами(замечания, литературу и т.д.)?

Comment: @VadimMorozov да, разумеется

Comment: @Yura Ivanov Понял, спасибо, но возможно понадобиться вытаскивать по несколько значений, так что лучше знать)

Comment: @YuraIvanov тут можно поспорить. Я, к примеру, использую ретрофит как раз для того, чтобы избежать работы с json напрямую. Десериализатор же вынуждает работать с json руками. Механизм десериализации понадобился мне лишь однажды, когда потребовалось вырезать из тела запроса одно из полей. Так что тут дело вкуса, кому как удобней

Comment: @P. Ilyin кстати о применении здесь retrofit'a, в MainActivity мы будем прописывать такой длинный путь к нужному ресурсу или можно как то сразу перепрыгнуть?

Comment: @P.Ilyin вы удивитесь, но ретрофит таки работает с json напрямую, используя десериализаторы, например gson, который притом использует медленную рефлексию. Возможно, вам проще скормить json pojo генераторам и создавать десятки классов, которые просто не будут использоваться, это ваше право. Что касается десериализаторов вообще, вам просто видимо не приходилось встречать причудливые значения, например для даты, все впереди...

Comment: @YuraIvanov все, что вы говорите, конечно, правда и good practice. НО! Действительно в своем ответе я должен был привести кучу теории из документации к ретрофиту, чтобы у товарища, задавшего вопрос, глаза на лоб полезли от обилия информации? Или может лучше привести самое простое, самое лобовое решение проблемы? А пользователь уже сам пускай углубляются в эти дебри? К тому же, я вижу, что вы не торопитесь опубликовывать свой более правильный ответ

Comment: @P.Ilyin вы же сами сказали "можно поспорить"... я жду вашего ответа на комментарий Вадима о том, чтобы "сразу перепрыгнуть". btw, ссылку про десериализаторы я дал...

Comment: @YuraIvanov вы, похоже, только и поняли, что можно поспорить, а объект спора как-то упустили. Вадим пускай заводит отдельный вопрос, комментарии - не тот формат

Comment: @P.Ilyin На самом деле с удовольствием посмотрел бы пример)
А то набрел на то что, что можно вроде как по позиции обратиться к get'еру.

Answer (score 0):

В общем ребята, кто столкнулся с похожей ситуации или как решил эту проблему я исходя из советов на стаке.

Создал несколько классов(models) для каждого вложенного JSON-объекта/массива(из скрина выше получились следующие модели: *Form*, *Groups*, *Controls*), так как на сколько я могу судить, создавать много классов в одном - есть bad practice.
После того как выстроил логику классов, что за чем идёт и какие объекты/массивы внутри находятся, используя библиотеку retrofit, в классе *MainActivity* сделал следующий запрос:

```
public void onResponse(Call<DropDown> call, Response<DropDown> response) {
            DropDown jsonResponse = response.body();
            Log.d("type",jsonResponse.getForm().getmGroupss().get(1).getmControls().get(2).getTitle()+"");
```

Надеюсь, будет полезно(**не забываем читать комментарии в вопросе**).